# How to creating Accounts and Contacts programatically?

Tags: vtiger

I want to create an Account programmatically and then create a number of Contacts programmatically and associate them with the Account.

We have a number of vTiger instances that run on the same server and I am building a custom manager to add Accounts and Contacts to targeted vTiger instances.

In the custom manager the workflow is a user can select the target vTiger instance from a select menu, this action fills out some details in the custom manager form. On submitting this form the system navigates to the targeted vTiger instance and creates the account and contact.

I had a look at the [Webservice tutorial](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials)  but with our infrastructure we would prefer to avoid HTTP. I can (folder) navigate to a vTiger instance and invoke a class. I can then pass an array to that class to create the Account or Contact. This way we are reducing security risks by using HTTP and everything is internal.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an Account you can create a function will contains this:

(You must include all mandatories fields)

```
global $current_user;
include_once 'modules/Accounts/Accounts.php';

$my_account = new Accounts();
$my_account->column_fields['accountname'] = $accountName;
$my_account->column_fields['accounttype'] = $accountType;
$my_account->column_fields['email1'] = $email;
$my_account->column_fields['assigned_user_id'] = $current_user->id;
$my_account->save('Accounts');
```

To update an existing Account:

```
$moduleName = 'Accounts';
$recordModel= Vtiger_Record_Model::getInstanceById($accountId,$moduleName);
$recordModel->set('accountname', $myNewAccountName);
$recordModel->set('mode', 'edit');
$recordModel->save();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this only works if you are logged into the vTiger instance. I am trying to create an account with an external script where I am not logged in.

Comment: I just spotted it creates entries in the db accounts table vtiger_account and vtiger_crmentity but they do not display in the vTiger Account list. It throws an error after CRMEntity->insertIntoCrmEntity( ) - CRMEntity.php on line 284 - I'll post any solution I find